# dynamically created radio group not hearing checked change listener

Tags: android, radio-button, android-radiogroup

i have created a dynamic radio group with with 3 radio buttons..my problem is that all 3 buttons can be clicked and radio group is not hearing for check changes. I would like the default behavior of radio buttons inside radio group where only one radio button can be checked.

```
RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[question.getAnswers().size()];
RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(getActivity());
rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
questionContainer.addView(rg);

for (int i =0; i < question.getAnswers().size(); i++) {
    rb[i] = new RadioButton(getActivity());
    rb[i].setText(question.getAnswers().get(i));
    rg.addView(rb[i]);
}
rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int checkedId) {
         Log.e(debugTag, "radio button position: "+checkedId);
    }
});
```

questionContainer is my fragment's LinearLayout container

Comment: did you try setting ids to your dynamically added radio buttons? `rb[i].setId(some_unique_id);`

Comment: yes, but with no results...

Comment: i think the problem derives from the library i use to create the radio buttons...android default buttons work as expected...just tested

Comment: yeah exactly. I also tried it. what's the library ?

Comment: https://github.com/rey5137/material#features

Comment: oh I used it too. The problem is that this library uses `CompoundButton` instead of `RadioButton`. There are some solutions to this problem, check [this](https://github.com/rey5137/material/issues/49) and [this](https://github.com/rey5137/material/issues/161)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem actually derived from the library i use to create the radio button. After some digging and 2 very useful links provided by @R. Kirill i do not create a RadioGroup to place the radio buttons inside it. I just handle CompoundButton(RadioButton extend from this class) checked change listener myself.

```
final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[question.getAnswers().size()];

com.rey.material.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener c = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            for (RadioButton aRb : rb) {
                aRb.setChecked(aRb == compoundButton);
            }
        }
    }
};

for (int i =0; i < question.getAnswers().size(); i++) {
    rb[i] = new RadioButton(getActivity());
    rb[i].setId(i);
    rb[i].setOnCheckedChangeListener(c);
    rb[i].setChecked(false);
    rb[i].setText(question.getAnswers().get(i));
    questionContainer.addView(rb[i]);
}
```